# How do I set an .m4r file ringtone I airdropped to my iPhone 13?

Tags: iphone, ios, ringtones

I have an old .m4r file on my Macbook, which I used AirDrop to copy to my iPhone 13. There's no way to set it as my ringtone, however.

In the ringtone settings page, it's not there, and if I go to the Files app I can open the .m4r file and even play it, but there's no option to "set as ringtone".

Comment: I had the feeling Apple made this much much harder over the years. Google says you either use Garage Band or some third party app to force it in there. I've never needed to do it since the days you could just drop them on iTunes, so I hope someone has a simpler method. Wish you luck.

Comment: @Tetsujin I figured it out. I had to tap "Download all downloadable ringtones from the store" in my iphone 13's ringtone settings page

Answer (score 9):

Wow! I finally got it but it was extremely counterintuitive. I had to go to the Ringtone settings page on my iphone 13 and there was a section with "Store" with two buttons, "Tone Store", and something like "Download all downloadable ringtones from the store".

I had no interest in purchasing ringtones from the store, so I didn't bother tapping this at first, but I figured what the heck, and **I tapped the "download all downloadable ringtones", and the .m4r file's ringtone instantly appeared in the ringtones list** in settings, and I was able to use it.

It is astonishing that this worked, since my .m4r file was in my Files app on my iphone 13 the entire time, so in no sense did I "download" it.

Comment: Glad you got it. I have to admit that as I loaded my phone up with a whole slew of potential ringtones a decade ago, I haven't paid it much attention since. Well found! :)

Comment: Great find! I have a feeling that this might not be what Apple intended; this handy feature might stop working soon.

Comment: It didn't work for me.  File was on the phone.  And now the button to download is gone.

Comment: This does not work. iOS is a joke. The simplest things are impossible.

Answer (score 4):

For me, dragging the .m4r files directly onto the Finder window showed it in iOS Settings right away:

- download .m4r to somewhere on my mac
- plug in the iPhone, wait for it to show up in the Finder sidebar (macOS 13.4.1)
- drag the .m4r file into any part of the plain, not-draggable-looking "General" tab
- open Settings.app on the device (iPhone SE, iOS 15.7.7), the ringtone shows up with the same name as the .m4r's filename